# override custom image path for bundled products only

Tags: module

how can i override custom image path for bundled proudcts
i am using below code in catalog > category > custom design update

```
<reference name="product.info.media">
      <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>path_to_media.phtml</template>
      </action>
</reference>
```

now i want to do it via module i made config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Module_Customgroup>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Module_Customgroup>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

1:where should i write it in config.xml
2: should it be used inside  ?
3: how to limit it so it can be applied on bundled products only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following steps. It will work for you.

> Step 1: Create file app\etc\modules\Module_Customgroup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
         <Module_Customgroup>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends/>
        </Module_Customgroup>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Create file app/code/local/Module/Customgroup/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Customgroup>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Module_Customgroup>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customgroup>
                    <file>customgroup.xml</file>
                </customgroup>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> Step 3: Create file
>   app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/customgroup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
        <reference name="product.info.media">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>path_to_media.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
</layout>
```

> Step 4: Create file
>   app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/path_to_media.phtml

```
<?php
/* Using following condition you can limit it to work for only bundle product */
//if($product->getTypeId() == "bundle"): ?>
    //Your Code Here
<?php //endif; ?>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: can step3 be included in step2

Comment: @mourjewels No. It is separate file under your theme.

Comment: @mourjewels I have modified step:2 file. Please use latest one

Comment: @mourjewels Is this code worked for you?

Comment: send u message pls reply

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do that is add under your `local.xml` the `path_to_media.phtml` template. This update will be applied just for bundle products.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
            <reference name="product.info">
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="path_to_media.phtml">
                        <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.media.after" as="after" />
                    </block>
            </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
</layout>
```